# S3 jQuery objectProperties file (key) naming and path?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I have a working implementation of the S3 + jQuery setup to my own bucket.  One problem I noticed was by default the object created defaults to the UUID name for the file rather than the original file name.  Adjusting my request to include objectProperties key "filename" resolved this BUT it will only upload to the root of my bucket.  I understand that S3 and object storage lacks real directory structure it just a big bucket however the ability to reference an object such as bucketname/somepath/filename.jpg allows you to create code around this "pseudo path".  My application does this now in the S3 bucket (and relies heavily upon it).  Is there any object property that I can use to define the path to the file when I upload it (in essence creating this virtual key path to the object in S3?)  I need the workflow to be : https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/somefakedirname/anotherfakedirname/photo.jpg.  Is there any way to create that with the S3 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can also define a function value for the [`objectProperties.key` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#objectProperties.key).  For example:

```
objectProperties: {
   key: function(fileId) {
      return 'dir1/dir2/dir3/' + this.getName(fileId);
   },
}
```